# How to use window url in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, youtube

currently I am working with Node.js.

YouTube Video Link: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LnFbVzf7D4"

My Domain: "Test123YouTube.com"

When I type "https://www.Test123youtube.com/watch?v=6LnFbVzf7D4" in the search bar, I want my website to be directly embedded with the YouTube video.

How do I do that? Can not find a suitable answer to this!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't tell what you're asking for help with.  Please describe in more detail what you want help with.

Comment: My sample link: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ha4tRQwKIUg"

My domain is "Test123youtube.com".

When I type "https://www.Test123youtube.com/watch?v=ha4tRQwKIUg" in the search bar, my website should load with the video from the top URL.

Comment: Please add your additional explanation to your question itself.  You can use the "edit" link below your question to do so.

Comment: I have changed it

Comment: So, this is a very general question.  It sounds like you're basically asking how to use nodejs to make a dynamic website that looks at the query parameter of a URL.  That's pretty broad.  I'd suggest you start by looking at the [Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) mini-framework for making a web server in nodejs and then you can examine `req.query` on an incoming request to see what the `v=6LnFbVzf7D4` part the URL is and then you can generate the appropriate web page to embed that video, probably by generating a youtube embedded video in the web page you return.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, here's a simple app that will do what you proposed:

```
const app = require('express')();

// will respond to /watch?v=xxxxx
// xxxxx is a youtube video ID
// returns a web page with that youtube video embedded in it
app.get("/watch", (req, res) => {
    const youtubeID = req.query.v;
    if (youtubeID) {
        const pageHTML = `<html><head></head><body>
        <iframe width="800" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${youtubeID}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </body></html>`;
        res.send(pageHTML);
    } else {
        res.status(400).send("Missing ?v=xxxxx in URL");
    }
});

// start web server on port 80
app.listen(80);
```

You would install the Express module in this project directory and then run this.

When the `/watch?v=xxxx` route is sent to this server, it will return a web page with the youtube video that corresponds to that video ID embedded into the web page where the user can then interact with it.  You can obviously use much richer HTML content around it than the barebones page here (I would probably be using an HTML template system such as nunjucks for something like this).

Comment: @HundeStaubsauger - I provided an example for you.  Does something like this work for you?